# Scripts are not working in web browser control

Tags: javascript, c#, google-maps, webbrowser-control

I used web browser control to load google maps in my .net app. here is the code..

```
string keyword = "colombo";
    private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        StringBuilder query = new StringBuilder();
        query.Append("http://maps.google.com/maps?q=");
        try
        {
            query.Append(keyword);

            Browser.Navigate(query.ToString());
        }
        catch (Exception)
        {                
            throw;
        }
    }
```

but after loading the result page for the given `keyword`(here "colombo") even if I click buttons in the page it doesn't work. what am I missing...?

Comment: put your whole script here...

Comment: @Rony: I think it is the script produced by google maps, not his own script.

Comment: @odyss-jii-do u know where she had puten up click event code??

Comment: no click events. when the form loads it automatically loads the Google map. and odyss is right. they are Google map scripts.

Comment: For the love of God, don't use a StringBuilder to add two strings. The overhead of creating one is much bigger.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
string keyword = "colombo";
private void Form1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    String query = "";
    query="http://maps.google.com/maps?q=";
    try
    {
        query+=keyword;

        Browser.Navigate(query);
    }
    catch (Exception)
    {                
        throw;
    }
}
```

try this one without StringBuilders...